# I want to learn, why: Footer` import should occur before import of `components/Menu` import/order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, eslint

Why does occur that?

./pages/index.tsx
3:1  Error: `components/Footer/Footer` import should occur before import of `components/Menu`  import/order

Comment: It sounds like you have a lint rule that enforces that. The most obvious reason it's out of order is if they are supposed to be alphabetical. F is before M

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your time, appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it should be ordered alphabetically.

Check the rule here:

https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/order.md

```
// 5. "sibling" modules from the same or a sibling's directory
import bar from './bar';
import baz from './bar/baz';
```

This is a sibling module, both are from components, so they should be ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Wow I notices a few hours ago! But I was not sure 100% Now I can confirm thanks community! ✨